# My dipstick in my car was dry and I added 6 quarts and it was still bone dry. I let it idle in my driveway for 20 minutes and I smelled oil burning

Tags: dipstick

I checked my dipstick in my 2010 Lincoln town car and it was bone dry so I added 6 quarts and it was still bone dry. I put the key in the ignition and started it and let it run for about 20 minutes in my driveway and when I came out of my house to check the oil it smelled like oil was burning.

Comment: How much oil should it hold?

Comment: Give some history.  Did you think the engine should have oil in, or had you emptied it?

Comment: Did you check for leaks?

Comment: Was there oil on the engine after you ran it for 20 minutes?

Comment: Why did you leave it running for 20 unattended after just adding oil?

Comment: Have you ever seen the correct oil level on the dipstick before?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the engine you have the capacity for your engine oil is 5.5 or 6 quarts. It is impossible for you to add 6 quarts of oil in this engine and read an empty dipstick without oil leaking from the fill point or underneath the engine in that short amount of time. I am convinced that you are looking at the wrong dipstick, and overfilling the engine with oil. The only answer I can give you is to read the owners manual and become familiar with how to check and maintain fluid levels. Or have someone knowledgeable on this help you learn. This car should not be started at all until it is looked at. 6 quarts of extra oil can possibly cause significant damage to your engine. If by chance it has no engine oil it would destroy the engine no doubt about it.

Comment: Or he filled the oil in the wrong place

Comment: That is possible too, which reinforces that this car should not be started. He did smell oil after running for 20 minutes, so I am assuming it's overfull. For the engines sake I hope you're wrong.